# If I change Apollo cache, Is this change reflected without refresh?

Tags: react-native, apollo-client, apollo-server, gql

I use apollo server and graphql.

I move from screen A to screen B.
And in screen B, I change data of screen A.

So in order to reflect this change, I change cache of that data.

And I navigate.goBack() to screen A.

Then this modified cache will be applied in screen A?

For me, it doesn't.

So I wonder whether because I incorrectly modified my cache or just because it's regardless of cache modification, screen should be same since navigate.goBack doesn't refresh screen.

I can use refetch option of useQuery for this but in that case flatlist scroll goes on top, so I don't want.

Comment: Modifying the cache should reflect on the screen. Incorrectly modified cache will not be visible. Once you modify the cache, console log the cache and find the data of your queries. Compare your old cache to the new one and see if there is any missing data.